# How to create concave block?

Tags: html, css

How to create concave block with image on background (for example slider)? What I need:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added `:pseudo` element to add circular effect with `border-radius`

```css
.main {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.main img {
  position: relative;
}
.main div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  z-index: 0;
}
.main div:after {
  content: '';
  width: 150%;
  left: -25%;
  background: white;
  height: 150%;
  top: -15%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <img src="http://placeimg.com/400/300/animals">
  <div>
    Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
  </div>
</div>
```